# Como regresar a una página que ocupas POST

Tags: php, formularios, post

Tengo un form A que me manda a una página con un form B (obtengo los datos de A con el método post), el submit de B hace modificaciones en una base de datos y después debe regresarme a B pero obviamente al poner header('Location: B.php') me sale error porque no estoy enviando los datos de A.

Comment: Por qué no guardas los datos en variables de sesión conforme mandes los datos por post en cada formulario ? de esa manera estés donde estés podrás tener acceso a ellos sin preocuparte de en qué formulario estés

Answer (score 1):

Deberias ser mas especifico para poder comprender mejor tu problema y darte una mejor respuest.

Que tipo de datos estas enviando del form A al B y del B a php?
Por que POST?

Podrias intentar usar Ajax en vez de ir cambiando de pagina en pagina y luego volver atras.

Pero si de algo te sirve tambien podrias intentar con JavaScript

```
<?php 
    #Tu codigo aqui
    #Una vez finalizado en vez de usar location(); intenta lo siguiente
?>
<script>
    (function(){
        window.history.back();
    })()
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear una función para tu modelo, te dejo aquí mi ejemplo, puedes moficarlo a tu manera.

```
function insertarUsuario($nombre_usuario,$password_usuario, $email_usuario,$direccion_usuario,$poblacion_usuario,$cp_usuario )
{
    $objData = new ConnectDB();
    $usuario_activo = 0;
    include '../controller/CrearUsuario.php';

    if (!filter_var($email_usuario, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        echo("is a valid email address");
        //echo("$email_usuario");
    } else {
        echo("$email_usuario is not a valid email address");
    }

    $stmt = $objData->prepare('INSERT INTO Usuarios (nombre_usuario, password_usuario, email_usuario, direccion_usuario, poblacion_usuario, cp_usuario, usuario_activo) '
        . 'VALUES (:nombre_usuario, :password_usuario, :email_usuario, :direccion_usuario, :poblacion_usuario, :cp_usuario, :usuario_activo)');
    $stmt->bindParam('nombre_usuario', $nombre_usuario);
    $stmt->bindParam('email_usuario', $email_usuario);
    $password_usuario = password_hash($password_usuario, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $stmt->bindParam("password_usuario", $password_usuario,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam('direccion_usuario', $direccion_usuario);
    $stmt->bindParam('poblacion_usuario', $poblacion_usuario);
    $stmt->bindParam('cp_usuario', $cp_usuario);
    $stmt->bindParam('usuario_activo', $usuario_activo);


    $stmt->execute();
    echo("Se ha registrado con exito");

}
?>
```

No te olvides de llamar la función desde tu controlador. Te dejo aquí el código también:

```
$nombre_usuario = htmlentities($_POST['nombre'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');
$password_usuario = $_POST['password'];
$email_usuario = $_POST['email'];
$direccion_usuario = htmlentities($_POST['address'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');
$poblacion_usuario = htmlentities($_POST['ciudad'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');
$cp_usuario = htmlentities($_POST['cp'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');


insertarUsuario($nombre_usuario,$password_usuario, $email_usuario,$direccion_usuario,$poblacion_usuario,$cp_usuario );
```

Puedes revisar el html también.

```
Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre"/> <br/>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" /> <br/>
        Email: <input type="text" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$"/> <br/>
        Dirección: <input type="text" name="address"/> <br/>
        Ciudad: <input type="text" name="ciudad" equired size="30 "/> <br/> <!--30 caracteres y espacio -->
        Código Postal *: <input type="text" name="cp" required size="5" pattern="[0-9]{5}" title="El codigo postal tiene 5 caracteres"/> <br/>
```

El `post` en el `form` deberías poner tu fichero del controlador y listo ya lo tienes, suerte.